# Why is A = Tuple{4, 5} valid Julia syntax? And what does this mean?

Tags: types, julia

I'm going through the Julia documentation and when trying something out in Julia REPL I accidently typed `A = Tuple{4,5}` instead of `A = (4,5)`. To my surpise this did not throw an error.

Why is this `A` a `DataType` even though 4 and 5 are instances of `Int64`/`Int32`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Tuple{Int, String}` is the type of `(123, "hello")` similarly `Tuple{4, 5}` would be the type of a two-element tuple whose first value has type `4` and whose second value has type `5`. Of course, `4` and `5` are not the types of any values, so this is not actually the type of any value that can exist, but it's still a type, just an "uninhabited" one, i.e. one that doesn't have any instances. In general, Julia's type system is perfectly ok with types that are uninhabited.

We could prevent the object `Tuple{4, 5}` from being constructed by insisting that the parameters of `Tuple` must be types, but that just hasn't been done since there's no real harm in letting people construct this type object. Even if Julia did prevent you from constructing `Tuple{4, 5}` by insisting that the arguments to `Tuple` are types, this would still be valid *syntax* since, in general, the parameters to `Tuple` are arbitrary expressions and `4` and `5` are perfectly valid expressions that just happen to evaluate to values that don't make much sense as parameters to `Tuple`. Similarly, if I wrote `Tuple{A, B}` that would be valid syntax even if we had `A = 4` and `B = 5`. So while we could prevent `Tuple{4, 5}` from being constructed, this would always be valid syntax.

It should also be noted that even though the parameters to `Tuple` don't make sense unless they are types, it is often useful for type parameters to be values, rather than types. For example, the type of `[1 2; 3 4]` is `Array{Int, 2}` where the second type parameter is an integer, indicating that the array is two-dimensional while the first parameter gives the element type of the array.

Comment: To take a slight step back, curly braces are how you describe _type parameters_, and defining which sorts of parameters are "sensible" is entirely up to the type itself (with [one limitation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.isbits)). Many types use non-type parameters (like the dimensionality of arrays, for example).

Comment: Having numerical values as type parameters are useful as well. `Array{Float64, 2}` for example

Comment: Y'all should feel free to edit my answer to add this stuff as well.